# Cartesian product of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Take two topological spaces $(X,ł_x)$ and  $ (Y,ł_y)$.  Is $ł: = \{A \times B \quad| \quad A \in ł_x, B \in ł_y \}$ a topology on $X \times Y$?

My firts question:

$U_1$, $U_2$ $\in$ $ł$,

I have to check if $U_1 \bigcup U_2 \in ł$. I don't know how $U_1$ and $U_2$ looks.

Is that correctly?  $U_1 := \{C \times D \quad | \quad C\in A, D \in B\}$

Comment: The form for $U_1$ is not right. Think about how this connects to the definition of your proposed topology.

Comment: Is it a pair where first element belongs to $A$ and the second belongs to $B$ ?

Comment: No it’s a pair where they belong to the first and second topologies, respectively. That’s what your definition of the product topology means.

Comment: $U_1 = \{ C \times D , C \in ł_x, D \in ł_y \} $ ?

Comment: Yes that’s right. Now that you have the right form, try taking a union and see how it breaks.

Comment: I am not sure what union of cartesian product means.  I have $C \times D$ from $U_1$ and I have $E \times F$ from $ U_2$.  Can I take an element from first set $(a, b) $ and from second $(c, d) $ and just sum  it?  $(a+c,  b+d) $?

Comment: There may not be a notion of summation on this space. The union here is the set theory union, meaning an element of the union of two sets is an element of either the first or the second set. In other words, in your case it is either an element of $U_1$ or $U_2$. If you understand this, then the next step is to see why the union is not itself a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

As an example let $X=Y=\mathbb R$ and let them both be equipped with the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.

Now suppose that $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that: $$A\times B=(0,2)^2\cup(2,4)^2\tag1$$

Then $\langle1,1\rangle\in(0,2)^2\subseteq A\times B$ so that $1\in A$.

Also $\langle3,3\rangle\in(2,4)^2\subseteq A\times B$ so that $3\in B$.

Then $\langle1,3\rangle\in A\times B$.

This contradicts $(1)$ since $\langle1,3\notin(0,2)^2\cup(2,4)^2$ and we conclude that no sets $A,B$ exist that satisfy $(1)$.

So the collection you mention is not closed under unions hence is not a topology.